# Process engineer dairy

Tags: thermodynamics

For a project I really need to know some number I can't seem to produce  myself.

We are flashing water  at 75°C. The water after flash-cooling is 67°C. Constant pressure is 0.27 bar (absolute) flow rate is 15000 kg/per hour.

How much water is vaporized?
I used this m = Q / (h_vap - h_liq) but i do not have enough experience

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: What calculations have you done so far? Can you show them in your question?

Comment: The amount of water flashed should be equal to the amount of energy removed from the water ie the mass, the temperature difference and the specific heat and then factor in the losses.

Comment: In order for flow to exist, there must be a pressure gradient so it is not constant pressure. For the system, depending on how it is sealed/contained, you should be able to rig up a system to measure the mass of liquid water.